# How do I use a directory path variable from an Action Listener from one class in another?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm new to programming and I've, like an idiot, decided to have my first project to be one way beyond my level.  I haven't had much success trying to find a solution to this problem on the site yet, so I'm asking.

So, I have a button that creates a file with a name from user input and then creates directories that include that file. It's in class "NewProject".

```
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Create");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String projectName = textPane.getText();
            File projectFolder = new File("C:\\Jibberish\\" + projectName);
            File projectStart = new File("C:\\Jibberish\\" + projectName + 
           "\\" + "Project" + "\\" + "text.rtf");
```

Now, in another class, "workspace", I have  a JTree and a JEditorPane.  I want to know how I can get a variable like "projectStart" in the "workspace" class so I could use the directory as a model for the JTree and the file "text.rtf" as the default text in the JEditor.

If more info is needed, I'll try to provide it. 
Please answer as if I don't know anything because I don't. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got you correctly but for handing projectStart over into workspace.class you could create a private class-variable and create a getter-method for it.

```
private File projectStart = null;
private void buttonAction(){ //this is where your ActionListener stuff happens
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Create");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String projectName = textPane.getText();
            File projectFolder = new File("C:\\Jibberish\\" + projectName);
            projectStart = new File("C:\\Jibberish\\" + projectName + 
           "\\" + "Project" + "\\" + "text.rtf");
}
public File getProjectStart(){ //this method makes your projectStart-variable accessible for other classes
    return projectStart;
}
```

In your workspace class you can then use this variable by calling it similar to this:

```
private void foo(){
    NewProject np = new NewProject();
    File copyOfProjectStart = np.getProjectStart();
}
```

Hope this helps you.